# How could an AI be used to improve the teaching and learning of mathematics?

Tags: math, applications, education

I have been working with AI methods. I am thinking about how my daughter (and also other kids) could learn mathematics with the help of AI. For example, how could an AI be used to show the mistakes that a kid does during the learning path?

Answer (score 1):

Fundraising is probably the most realistic answer with the biggest effect. Similar to simply [adding blockchain to the company name helps](https://www.google.de/amp/s/www.bloomberg.com/amp/news/articles/2018-01-22/blockchain-name-changes-are-still-proving-fodder-for-stock-rally).

For the question of real application, I should first say that I'm a machine learning engineer who works as a consultant. I had mathematics as a minor subject during bachelor's and Master's degree, which is like 80% of a bachelor's degree in mathematics. Mainly the bachelor's thesis is missing. I also gave private mathematics lessons.

I would distinguish learning mathematics at school from University. It's completely different. However, for this question it does not make much of a difference. It's also not super important that you ask it for math. It's about learning in general.

Machine learning tools can support for several minor tasks:

- Figuring out how a symbol is called (I build write-math.com for that as a bachelor's project)
- Figuring out what a symbol means
- Getting relevant papers / parts of the lecture notes for a given problem
- Helping to digitalize stuff for easier sharing / content creation
- Learning things by heart: there are some nice apps like Anki which help you to learn arbitrary stuff by heart. The learning algorithm could potentially be improved by AI